# Is the number of infinite subsets of Z equal to the size of R?

Tags: nt.number-theory

From Cantor we know that |R| = 2^|Z|. That is, |R| is equal to the number of subsets of Z. Is it also true that |R| is equal to the number of *infinite* subsets of Z?

Comment: This question should be closed; it is more appropriate for math stack exchange. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because there are only countably many finite subsets of Z.

Comment: That was actually going to be my next question. Thanks :D

Comment: A slightly more difficult problem is to construct continuum many (infinite) subsets of N such that any two have a finite intersection. I leave it to you as an exercise! Hint: change N to Q.

Answer (score 0):

The set of subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ can be seen as the set of all functions $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\{0,1\}$. And this last set can be seen as the set of all sequences of 0 and 1. With this last point of view, it is easy to see that there exists a bijection between this set and, for instance, the interval $[0,1]$.